# Importing massive dataset in Neo4j where each entity has differing properties

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, bigdata, graph-databases

I'm trying to bulk load a massive dataset into a single Neo4j instance. Each node will represent a general `Entity` which will have specific properties, e.g.:

- label
- description
- date

In addition to these there are zero or more properties specific to the `Entity` type, so for example if the `Entity` is a `Book`, the properties will look something like this:

- label
- description
- date
- **author**
- **first published**
- ...

And if the `Entity` is a `Car` the properties will look something like this:

- label
- description
- date
- **make**
- **model**
- ...

I first attempted to import the dataset by streaming each `Entity` from the filesystem and using Cypher to insert each node (some 200M entities and 400M relationships). This was far too slow (as I had expected but worth a try).

I've therefore made use of the bulk import tool `neo4j-admin import` which works over a CSV file which has specified headers for each property. The problem I'm having is that I don't see a way to add the additional properties specific to each `Entity`. The only solution I can think of is to include a CSV column for every possible property expressed across the set of entities, however I believe I will end up with a bunch of redundant properties on all my entities.

**EDIT1**

Each `Entity` is unique, so there will be some 1M+ types (labels in Neo4j)

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/) command of [neo4j-admin](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin/) supports importing from multiple node and relationship files.

Therefore, to support multiple "types" of nodes (called `labels` in neo4j), you can split your original CSV file into separate files, one for each Entity "type". Each file can then have data columns specific to that type.

[UPDATED]

Here is one way to support the import of nodes having arbitrary schemata from a CSV file.

1. The CSV file should not have a header.
2. Every property on a CSV line should be represented by an adjacent pair of values: 1 for the property name, and 1 for the property value.

With such a CSV file, this code (which takes advantage of the APOC function [apoc.map.fromValues](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#map-functions)) should work:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///mydata.csv" AS line
CREATE (e:Entity)
SET e = apoc.map.fromValues(line);
```

NOTE: the above code would use strings for all values. If you want some property values to be integers, booleans, etc., then you can do something like this instead (but this is probably only sensible if the same property occurs frequently; if the property does not exist on a line no property will be created in the node, but it will waste some time):

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///mydata.csv" AS line
WITH apoc.map.fromValues(line) AS data
WITH apoc.map.setKey(data, 'foo', TOINTEGER(data.foo)) AS data
CREATE (e:Entity)
SET e = apoc.map.fromValues(line);
```

Comment: Thanks @cybersam, I should have been more specific however, as each Entity in my example is unique (although some, by chance, may have the same properties). I don't think this solution will work. I'll edit my question to add this information.

Comment: Do you mean that every entity has a different schema?

Comment: Yes @cybersam, think of an entity as any real world item or concept... a car, a person, Communism, Lord Voldermort... each of these would have different properties (propbably not quite unique as most persons, for example, would have similar properties, but would not be contrained to have a set of properties which all persons have... one person may have (siblings [PROPERTY]) whilst another may not). It's a model where any concept or item can be represented.